# Is it Possible to use an anchor tag within an anchor tag?

Tags: html

```html
<a href="www.google.com">Google
 <a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</a>
```

will the links google.com take me to the google site and facebook.com link to the facebook site? will the both links work or not?

Comment: Why would you ever be doing this?

Comment: it was the question asked in the interview